# Website is not loading: This page is not available

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, debian-squeeze

I have got a webserver. It's running on a private VPS with debian 6.0.9. On top of it I have running a Lamp stack with apache 2. Until a few days ago all was working well. But since a few days the site seems to be down. Some details:

- When I do a ping to the website I get the right server.
- When I go to the website via a browser I get a browser page with: Could not load website.
- I have restarted Apache.
- The virtual host hasn't changed and is intact.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: View the access / error log. These will contain valuable information

Comment: The access log shows only ::1 - - [15/Jul/2014:21:09:18 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) (internal dummy connection)". BTW should www-data have access to the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per IRC chat:

- check your vhost syntax everytime you perform a change with https -S or apache2ctl -S
- check your site response from a client call wget mysite.com
- check apache/application logs, usually error.log or access.log in /var/log/apache
- check iptable changes are not causing a refused connection

Please confirm this fixed it for you